# prevent inserting of wrong data

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a database with two tables containing (the first) some regions an (the second) some offices:

```
Table Regions
IdRegion
Region

Table Offices
IdOffice
IdRegion
IdOffice
```

(I've also set IdRegion as foreign key)

In a third table I have two fields where I want to insert the office and the region where the office is located preventing from errors.

I've already prepared a form in which (selected a region) are showed only the offices located in the selected region but I'm asking myself if is there any way to set the database for refusing of wrong insert.

Otherwise I've thought to check that the IdRegion is the one inserted in the Offices table corresponding to the office selected before executing the INSERT query.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What I do understand: You want to record in which region offices are located. What I don't understand: What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're proposing making up a third table. I suppose that table will have IdOffice and IdRegion as its columns.  If you did this, you'd make a composite primary key consisting of both columns. And you'd make IdOffice a foreign key to your Offices table. Likewise you'd make IdRegion a fk to your Regions table.

But that three-table design doesn't make any sense unless you have a many-to-many relationship between Offices and Regions.  But you don't. You've put the IdRegion foreign key into your Offices table. That means you expect each office to be in just one region.

Comment: My third table has fields: "Person", "IdRegion", "IdOffice" (and so on) and I was worried about inserting wrong values into the fields  "IdRegion" and "IdOffice". I was afraid that was inserted an office of a different region.

I'm sorry because I think I was a bad builder while creating the third table: i've realized that the into the third table I need only the field 'IdOffice" an not both fields "IdRegion" and "IdOffice" as i've done. Thank you for your time